# Will Cassandra Java Driver close gracefully if there are pending requests?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

For example,

```java
 for(..){
     ses.executeAsync(statement);
 }
 ses.close();
```

will the driver shutdown until all requests were sent out?

Answer (score 5):

The connections associated with that Session will not be closed immediately if there are any pending requests on them.  Instead they will be scheduled to eventually close after 2*readTiimeoutMillis.

When a Session is closed, it discards each of its connections by calling `connection#closeAsync` which calls [connection#tryTerminate(false)](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.0.9.2/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Connection.java#L472).   Since tryTerminate is called with 'false' it will not force close the connection [unless there are no pending requests](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.0.9.2/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Connection.java#L501-L506).  If there are pending requests it [gets scheduled for deletion](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.0.9.2/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/Connection.java#L478) after 2*readTimeoutMillis.